# Can we have a warning for posts containing "i"?

Tags: feature-request

After reviewing edits on SO, I find that one of the biggest signs of a poorly written post is not capitalising the pronoun "I". A gentle reminder to use proper grammar should at least prompt people to make an effort to write more professionally. This ought to be triggered on the usage of "I" when it isn't capitalised (**outside** of *code samples* of course).

This might be a good prompt to urge users to put a little more effort into writing their questions.

Comment: This already seems to be caught to some extent by the quality filter. Most often users running into the filter, who come to Meta for an explanation, seem to have their posts blocked because of a lack of proper capitalization. But it's admittedly not a perfect filter.

Comment: Counter-proposal: Let's change the english language because capitalizing the personal pronoun is simply arrogant and presumptuous.

Comment: @user414076 We disagree. (Majestic plural of course)

Comment: IF YOU JUST KEEP CAPS LOCK ON AT ALL TIMES YOU WON'T HAVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: @Servy, `AND WITH COBOL YOU CAN KEEP DOING IT EVEN IN CODE SAMPLES`.

Comment: This check should also be performed during editing. I constantly reject suggested edits as "too minor" when all "i"'s (along similar capitalization/punctuation problems) are overlooked.

Comment: @Servy. [THANKS. IT'S SO MUCH EASIER TO WRITE NOW!](http://bash.org/?835030)

Comment: @TRiG **** me..

Comment: I'm frankly the most humble person in the world. It's just impossible to be more humble than I am. That's why I capitalize the letter 'I' - nobody else needs to, though.

Comment: Frankly, `i` should be blocked even in code!  Can we slap down anyone who tries to use that as a variable?.  `a` is not far behind. ... But, ironically, `l` is fine.  Especially in code like `l = 11 * I`.  It helps flush out people/apps/machines using bad fonts. ;)

Comment: @AwesomePoodles You don't use `i` as a loop variable of a `for` loop?  I virtually never use anything *but* `i`.

Comment: @Servy, Nope.  Always use things like `J`, `K`, etc.  So much easier to read, distinguish and globally search.

Comment: @Servy I alway name my `bookIndex`, `monthDay`, etc. I discourage juniors during code reviews from using monocharacter variables. It's just more readable... but this is all besides the point. My original comment is quite serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be improved even further by making the check for:

```
' i '
```

<sup>spaces on either side</sup>

Or RegEx:

```
\bi\b
```

Otherwise, it would pick up `iOS` and `iPad`. I wouldn't mind having a check for `I-pad` too, though.

Comment: No, not spaces on either side.  Just use RegEx: `\bi\b`.

Answer (score 1):

When one capitalization issue appears in a particular post, there tend to be others. To avoid being overzealous with the warning, perhaps we can consider a weighted check: if X number of capitalization problems are detected, raise the warning.

The following mistakes are common:

```
html
css
php
mysql
java
javascript
jquery
json
ajax (also appears as 'Ajax')
python
ruby
```